# One Hot Encoder Classes

Tags: python, text-classification, one-hot-encoding

I have a data with 46 classes. Because the 46th class is small in splitting it moves to tet and it doesn't exist in train. now my onehotencoder has 45 classes but after all I need to train my model with 46 classes. What can be done?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
num_labels = 46

#creating instance of one-hot-encoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

#perform one-hot encoding on 'team' column 
e_sh['one_hot_labels'] =list(encoder.fit_transform(e_sh[['Label']]).toarray())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to train the model with more classes, `OneHotEncoder` must be refitted on the new dataset with the new classes.

Otherwise, ignore them with `handle_unknown` just like you are doing.

Comment: how should I do the refitting? train it again? I don't have the 46th class in the train dataset. in splitting this happened because the 46th one was very small I guess.

Comment: Yes, you must train it again. However if you are not able to get some training data with the new class you can't do much i'm afraid. I you want your program to raise an exception at prediction phase if an unknown class is being fed to your encoder, use ``handle_unknown='error'``

Comment: where should I use it? in the model line itself?

Comment: You must be sure that all the classes are contained in your pandas dataframe colum ``e_sh[['Label']]`` and rerun either ``fit`` or ``fit_transform``